# ¿Cómo recuperar la acción al hacer un load?

Tags: jquery

Cuando mi página hace un `.load` -> `$("#video").load(" #video").fadeIn();` el siguiente código pierde su función, deja de funcionar:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('.play').on('click',function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            $("[id='next']")[0].click();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Antes de hacer el `.load` funcionaba.  ¿Qué atributo adicional debo agregar para que `.load` no afecte su funcionamiento?

Comment: No funciona porque no se ha terminado de cargar el dom, enciera la función dentro de un window on load

Comment: @NicolasAldana Ya lo agregue: `$(window).on( "load", function() {}` no funciona.

Comment: agrega document .ready

Comment: @NicolasAldana Puedes proporcionarme un ejemplo completo en http://jsfiddle.net/ y luego pasarme el link

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/su4b7rtz/